# JQuery selector with many function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

The method that I invoke:

```
vm.progress = function () {
    $('.progress-line').width('100%').animate({ width: 0 }, 5, 'linear', 1000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="progress-outer">
    <div class="progress-line red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress-outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.progress-line {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
```

It has to animate progress bar from 100% to 0 in 5 secs. But it doesn't work. However, if I separate methods into two functions and invoke them by clicking on button (and only), it works.

Comment: Please show the html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Time limit, you should use

```
$(".progress-line").animate({width: "100%"},5000); // time 5000 is in milliseconds
```

Here is the fiddle that may help you. I use background colors to show the animation

[https://jsfiddle.net/simerjit/rgskzcj5/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/simerjit/rgskzcj5/1/)

Check jquery animate function details here... http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Comment: I have to play animation from 100 to 0 everytime it executes ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzw76zgL/)). It doesn't animate second time. Also it has to reset width back to 0 before an animation.

Comment: you mean, at first width is 100% then using animation it will be decrease to 0%, Right?

Comment: If yes, then please check the same fiddle, I have updated that... You just need to set the width 100% then in jquery set animate to 0%

Comment: Thanks! Can you please edit the URL in the answer? (from rgskzcj5/1/ to rgskzcj5/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You wrote wrong syntax to chaining animate function check the below code

```
 setInterval(function () {
    $(".progress-line").animate({width:
   "100%"},5000).animate({width:"0%"},6000);   
   },5000);
```

Check working demo  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hidaytrahman/eurt5puy/)